# proof with complex numbers and open unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

Let $\Omega: = B (0,1) \subseteq\mathbb C$ (open unit disk) and $f: \Omega\to\mathbb C$ with $f (\Omega) \subseteq\mathbb R.$

Tasks:

(1) if $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0,$ then $f'(z_0) = 0.$

(2) $f$ is holomorphic (in $\Omega$), $f$ is constant

My idea : I know what complex differentiable means $$f'(z_0)=\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$$ exists. In (1) its $=0$ and if I use the polar coordinates, it has to be $r<1,$ because of the open unit disk. But I don’t know how to go on.